# some problems of using Python's Cryptography on Windows

Tags: python, module, cryptography, python-module

I would like to use the cryptography's module on Windows, I am using version 1.12 and Python 3.10.6, and I have some problems. Actually, when I run my script, I receive the error :

`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/edoua/Documents/cryptographie.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
  File "C:\Users\edoua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 16, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hmac import HMAC
  File "C:\Users\edoua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\hmac.py", line 10, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.hmac import _HMACContext
  File "C:\Users\edoua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "C:\Users\edoua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography import utils, x509
  File "C:\Users\edoua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.base import (
  File "C:\Users\edoua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\base.py", line 28, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.extensions import (
  File "C:\Users\edoua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\extensions.py", line 25, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.general_name import (
  File "C:\Users\edoua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\general_name.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import parseaddr
  File "C:\Users/edoua/Documents\email.py", line 18, in <module>
    server.login(email_address, email_password)
  File "C:\Users\edoua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 739, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "C:\Users\edoua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 641, in auth
    response = encode_base64(initial_response.encode('ascii'), eol='')
NameError: name 'encode_base64' is not defined
```

`

It is coming from the smtplib.py file. Also, I precise that the module works perfectly, I can use all the functions of the module base64. So the problem is coming from the word 'encode_base64'. Please help !

I tried to launch my program, and that error occures, I expected that it was going to work.

Comment: Please make a [mcve].  Showing one line of code doesn't give us enough information to fix it.

Comment: Please include the full traceback from that error message. What version of Python and what cryptography module and version are you using?

Comment: sorry I am quite new to StackOverflow, all your notices have been done. @Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a local module `C:\Users/edoua/Documents\email.py` that is shadowing the [`email`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html) module from the Python standard library. Rename `email.py` to something else, or move it to somewhere that isn't on the Python path.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment ! Email.py wasnt a module but one of my creation, so now i undertsand better why it wasn't working. Thank you so much !